# How to display ListView on top of (over the) other items in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` that displays recent Search items. I have added it in the Stack Layout of my Main page. I want to show `ListView` over the other UI elements just like this:[image] How can it be done.

I am currently using a new Page just for `SearchBar` and `ListView`. On the mainpage I have just a Search Button, when I click on that button, app navigates to the new Page that contains `SearchBar` and `ListView`. But I want it done on the same page. When Search button is clicked, `SearchBar` and `ListView` show become visible over the other UI elements.

Here is my code:

**On MainPage.xaml**

```
<Button Text="Search" Clicked="SearchButtonPressed" />
```

**C# Code**

```
void SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new SearchPage());
}
```

**SearchPage.xaml Code**

```
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar x:Name="SearchBar"
                TextChanged="Handle_SearchButtonPressed"
                Placeholder="Search places..."
                CancelButtonColor="Red" />

    <ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=list}" RowHeight="50" IsVisible="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Tapped="ViewCell_Tapped">
                    <Label Text="{Binding}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a grid:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Entry Grid.Row="0"
           Placeholder="SearchItem"
           TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"/>
    <Image Grid.Row="1"
           Aspect="Fill"
           Source="testImage.png"/>

        <ListView x:Name="ListView"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  VerticalOptions="Start"
                  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                  IsVisible="False"
                  HeightRequest="300"
                  BackgroundColor="White"
                  Opacity="0.8">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

</Grid>
```

if the text of the search entry changed, show the listview:

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
        ListView.IsVisible =  e.NewTextValue.Length > 0; 
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you put the list which you will use for suggestion to the bottom of xaml hierarchy, you will resolve it without navige to another page. In addition, if you use the searchbar and listview in the grid and give a same row, they will overlap. Ex:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="90" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <SearchBar
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        CancelButtonColor="Red"
        IsSpellCheckEnabled="False">
        <SearchBar.Margin>
            <OnPlatform Android="0,0,0,-5" />
        </SearchBar.Margin>
    </SearchBar>
    <Label
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        BackgroundColor="Gray" />
    <Frame
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0,21,0,21"
        Padding="8"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        BorderColor="Red"
        CornerRadius="20"
        HasShadow="False"
        VerticalOptions="End">
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label
                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                Text="Test"
                TextColor="Red" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
    <StackLayout
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        Opacity="0.8"
        VerticalOptions="End">
        <Label
            x:Name="LabelDescription"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="Test 2"
            TextColor="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
    <BoxView
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    <ListView
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Margin="0,50.5,0,0"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestionItems}"
        RowHeight="42"
        SeparatorVisibility="None"
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="58" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,10,0"
                            Text="{Binding item1}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,10,0"
                            Text="{Binding item2}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            BackgroundColor="Gray" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Error `<OnPlatform Android="0,0,0,-5" />` Property Margin does not support values of type `OnPlatform1(T)`. However, thanks for the idea. inside of Grid giving same row number for `ListView` and other UI items. But the accepted answer works, and demo images help to understand it well. Anyways +upvote.

Comment: try this: Margin="{OnPlatform Android='10,5,10,0'}" instead of <OnPlatform/>

https://montemagno.com/important-onplatform-changes-xamarin-forms/